# Java plot values in a virtual graph and find the integral area.

Tags: java, math

quick question. I got 10 000 lines with information. I have 2 values on each line. The line is in the format : (time , water speed). I want to use numerical integration to solve how much water passed the sensor, but I'm very confused to how I would go about solving this in Java.

I would assume a graph would be nice, but I don't need it to be graphical, so maybe a array-list would do the trick.

Any tips, hint and tricks would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [*Trapezoidal Rule*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) for this: sort the intervals by time, then calculate the sum as follows:

```
// assume that time is expressed using some class
Time[] time = ...
// assume that the water speed is double, expressed in volume per unit of time.
// Further assume that Time units match the units in the denominator of water speed,
// e.g. if the speed is in galons per minute, then the time unit is minutes;
// if the speed is in galons per second, then the time unit is seconds, and so on
double[] speed = ...

double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < time.length-1 ; i++) {
    double deltaT = time[i+1].subtract(time[i]).toTimeUnits();
    // This is the formula for the trapezoidal rule on non-uniform grid
    sum += (speed[i]+speed[i+1])*deltaT;
}
double totalFlow = sum / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have that data as (time, speed) pairs, and you want to integrate the total flow over a given period of time, why not just use numerical integration (e.g. Euler, Simpson, Runga-Kutta)?  Read the values and feed them into an integration routine and you're done.

Maybe [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//) would be a good place to start.

The graphical representation would be nice, and a good check on your numerical results, but it's not necessary.